# FileSystemWatcher - how use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystemwatcher

Good morning everyone,

I have a question about FileSystemWatcher - I want when the textfile H1.txt change value inside,
the label in my ASP.NET webForm will refresh.
What I do wrong?

```
 TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");


    Label1.Text = tr.ReadLine() + " °C";
    Label1.Text  += tr.ReadToEnd();

    tr.Close();

    FileSystemWatcher fwatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    

    fwatcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\Help\H1.txt"); 
    fwatcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");

    //types of events to watch 
    fwatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    fwatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


   fwatcher.Changed += Changed;




}

public void Changed(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Help\H1.txt");
    Label1.Text = tr.ReadLine() + " °C";
    Label1.Text += tr.ReadToEnd();

    tr.Close();

}
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `H1.txt` file, and what part of them you want to display in the `Label1`?

Comment: In H1.txt is only value of temperature - for example  25
and that 25 a want to refresh in label

Comment: You could try replacing everything inside the `Changed` handler with this line of code: `Label1.Text = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath).Trim() + " °C";`. Does it solve the problem?

Comment: When I manually edit that H1.txt nothing happened :(
I just want when is change the value inside H1.txt it will atomatically change in my runnig web in that Label1.

Comment: Can you help me? or Advice something?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr),

```
protected void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType != WatcherChangeTypes.Changed)
    {
        return;
    };
    try
    {
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(e.FullPath))
        {
            var text = tr.ReadLine() + " °C";
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
            context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage("server", text);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // ignore any error
    } 
}
```

[Repo](https://github.com/ChrisWong979/SignalRWebSite)